# Warning "mismatched contact IDs" when trying to update existing individual records

Tags: import, relationships, data-import

I'm updating the CiviCRM database with a list of individual records. All these individuals exist already in the database, but I need to create the link with existing organisations.
I've already done that for other imports and I use the relationship "Employee of" -> "Organisation Name (match to contact)" to do the relationship between the individual and its organisation.
When trying to import, I receive a message telling me that all my records have "mismatched contact IDs" 
and that no record has been updated.
Any idea ?
Thank you

More information on this : I have tested with a single record "Patrick Test" on the demo database - https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ with the same import scheme and all went well. I make the same with one record on my CiviCRM and I receive an error. I really do not know what to do now...

The exact error message for this one record test is :
*Total Rows 1   Total number of rows in the imported data.
Mismatched Rows (skipped)   1   Rows with mismatched contact IDs... (NOT updated). <
» Download Mismatched Contacts
Total Contacts  0   Total number of contact records created or modified during the import.*
The generated csv error file tells me that "Related contact required fields are missing." Which fields ? I really dont know...

Many thanks for you help

Comment: in the column that is your Org ID do you have any blanks? if so perhaps the warning is 'you had a row where you said to create a related org but you didn't give me an ID for that row'

Comment: Yes right Pete and thank you.
A "blank" relationship gives this result, even if the contact is correctly imported

Comment: cool. i added as an answer if you want to Accept and/or +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column that is your Org ID has any blanks you will get this warning. It doesn't mean anything failed in the import. It is basically saying 'you had a row where you said to create a related org but you didn't give me an ID for that row so i am just letting you know'

Answer (score 2):

Apart the right answer of Pete (thanks) here above, I have found something else who explain the problem I have : I had two relationships in my import scheme: the one for the "Member of" relation and the second for the "Employee of" relation. This cannot work... and I need to make two separate imports for each relation.